# Selenium - Selecting A Field With An Epoch Based Changing ID

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium in Eclipse. I have 2 date fields - a start date and an end date. When I click in the field a calendar date picker opens for me to select a date.
The problem is these fields have changing id's made up of the letters dp and an epoch time dynamically created when the field is selected.  And the end date div is nested inside the start date div. There doesn't appear to be anything else I can select to get the field.
I could have used maybe x-path starts-with but both date fields id's start with dp and then the rest of the number is a unique epoch.

This is the containing code for each field:

```
<div class="grid_d">
<input class="hasDatepicker" id="dp1462364240250" data-bind="datepicker: jobList.startDate, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: 'yy-M-dd' }, css: { error : !isStartDateValid() }" type="text">

<div class="grid_ed">
<input class="hasDatepicker" id="dp1462358450214" data-bind="enable: hasEnd, datepicker: jobList.endDate, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: 'yy-M-dd' }, css: { error : !isEndDateValid() }" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

How can I select these fields with changing id?

Comment: You can select these inputs by the following xpaths
`//div[@class="grid_d"]/input[1]`

`//div[@class="grid_ed"]/input`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. That doesn't work I get an error. but I think it is along the right lines.
ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: Share the link to get a clearer view of what it is being dealt with

Comment: how about using the data bind attribute?

Comment: The application I am testing is an internal app not available online.

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam Do you have an example?

Comment: @Leroy-S I have updated this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
By.cssSelector("input.hasDatepicker[data-bind*="jobList.startDate"]")
By.cssSelector("input.hasDatepicker[data-bind*="jobList.endDate"]")
```